# x-editable + bootstrap 3 + Twitter typeahead.js not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, x-editable

I tried to integrate Bootstrap3 with the awesome x-editable and typeahead.js, but I couldn't make it work:

I tried the following

- mark the element with data-type='typeaheadjs'
- add type='typeaheadjs' to $().editable()
- move all parameters to data-* attributes
- move all parameters to $().editable() arguments

but no luck.

HTML Code:

```
<div style="margin: 150px">
    <a href="#" id="username">Rome</a>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$('#username').editable({
    mode: 'inline',
    showbuttons: false,
    type: 'text',
    url: '/post',
    pk: 1,
    title: 'Enter an Italian city',
    typeahead: {
        local: ['Rome', 'Milan', 'Venice', 'Florence']
    }
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ggxbm/3/

even the provided example at http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#typeaheadjs does not work for me

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to include typeahead.min.js **AND typeaheadjs.js**

as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9q7Jd/1/ adding

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/inputs-ext/typeaheadjs/typeaheadjs.js
```

is fixing the issue.

you can found typeaheadjs.js in the zip archive in directory *inputs-ext/typeaheadjs* :
 https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/tree/master/src/inputs-ext/typeaheadjs